# How to save linked list in a file.txt?

Tags: c, function, file, pointers, linked-list

I can't save my linked list (liste chainée) in the file; it keeps resaving till the size of the file reaches 1.4GB; I was so surprised, I felt my pc gonna explode.
I know for sure the problem is in the saving function because when executing I was able to fill the linked list.
Anyway here is my program

**plz don't excute the prog **

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/***valeur d'un capteur d'humidite***/
typedef struct
{
    int heure;
    int minute;
}Date;
typedef struct//valeur d'une cellule/noeud
{
    char id[10];
    char id_capt[10];
    Date date_hr;
    int val_hum;//float ou int
}valeurs_hum;

typedef struct//liste chainee
{
    valeurs_hum capt;
    struct Element* suivant;
}Element;

typedef struct Liste Liste;
struct Liste
{
    Element *premier;
};
/************************************************/
Liste *initialisation()
{
    Liste *liste = malloc(sizeof(*liste));
    Element *nouveau = malloc(sizeof(*nouveau));//element->nouveau

    if (liste == NULL || nouveau == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Donner id = ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",nouveau->capt.id);
    if( strlen(nouveau->capt.id)==0)//peut etre ajouter au premier
    nouveau=NULL;
    else
    {
    printf("Donner id du capteur = ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",nouveau->capt.id_capt);
    printf("Donner date de prendre valeur d'humidite\n");
    printf("heure = ");
    scanf("%d",&nouveau->capt.date_hr.heure);
    printf("minite = ");
    scanf("%d",&nouveau->capt.date_hr.minute);
    //valeur du capteur aleatoire
    nouveau->capt.val_hum = rand() % 100 + 1;

    nouveau->suivant = NULL;
    liste->premier = nouveau;

    return liste;
    }
}
/********************************************/
void insertion(Liste *liste)
{
    /* Création du nouvel élément */
    Element *nouveau = malloc(sizeof(*nouveau));
    if (liste == NULL || nouveau == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Donner id = ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",nouveau->capt.id);
    if( strlen(nouveau->capt.id)==0)
    nouveau=NULL;
    else
    {
    printf("Donner id du capteur = ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",nouveau->capt.id_capt);
    printf("Donner date de prendre valeur d'humidite\n");
    printf("heure = ");
    scanf("%d",&nouveau->capt.date_hr.heure);
    printf("minite = ");
    scanf("%d",&nouveau->capt.date_hr.minute);
    //valeur du capteur aleatoire
    nouveau->capt.val_hum = rand() % 100 + 1;
        /* Insertion de l'élément au début de la liste */
        nouveau->suivant = liste->premier;
        liste->premier = nouveau;
        }
}
/*******************************************/
void afficherListe(Liste *liste)
{
    if (liste == NULL)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    Element *nouveau = liste->premier;//nouveau->courant

    while (nouveau != NULL)
    {
printf("\n id : %s", nouveau->capt.id);
printf("\n id du capteur : %s", nouveau->capt.id_capt);
printf("\n date de prendre valeur d'humidite = %d:%d",nouveau->capt.date_hr.heure,nouveau->capt.date_hr.minute);
printf("\n valeur du capteur :%d", nouveau->capt.val_hum);

nouveau = nouveau->suivant;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
/*************************************************/
void Sauvegarder(Liste *liste, FILE* pf)
{
int i;
Element *courant = liste->premier;

while(courant!=NULL)
fprintf(pf,"\n%s : %s : %d:%d : %d \n", courant->capt.id, courant->capt.id_capt, courant->capt.date_hr.heure,courant->capt.date_hr.minute,courant->capt.val_hum);
courant=courant->suivant;
}
/************************************************/
int main(void)
{
char* nomfich;
FILE * pf;
    int i,nbr_capt;
    Liste *l;
    Liste *l1;

nomfich=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
printf("\n Donnez le nom du fichier à créer :");
gets(nomfich);
/*--------------------------------------------*/
/*------------------Ecriture dans le fichier----------------*/
pf = fopen(nomfich, "a+");
//do{
    l=initialisation();

    printf("donner nbre capt = ");
    scanf("%d",&nbr_capt);
    for(i=0;i<nbr_capt;i++)
        insertion(l);
/*if( l==NULL)
break;
else*/
Sauvegarder(l, pf);
//}while(1);
fclose(pf);

return 0;
}
```

Here:

```
while(courant!=NULL)
fprintf(pf,"\n%s : %s : %d:%d : %d \n", courant->capt.id, courant->capt.id_capt, courant->capt.date_hr.heure,courant->capt.date_hr.minute,courant->capt.val_hum);
courant=courant->suivant;
```

I think I must add the pointers but couldn't figure it out

Comment: Begin with the compiler warnings and errors. Two points to note: `gets()` now isn't a C function, and `fflush(stdin)` is undefined.

Comment: `nomfich=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` - that's exactly one `char`. Which means for a string you can only input the null-terminator

Comment: "it keeps resaving till the size of the file atteined 1.4GB" Even if the linked list has only one entry? Or two? Or three? Can you modify your [mre] and show that you can create  and output (to console, not to file) a list of two entries?

Comment: The `while` loop in `Sauvegarder` needs braces, otherwise it will only execute the `fprintf` call and never the line after that

Comment: ...IOW you have an infinite loop, because `courant` is not modified.

Comment: @UnholySheep thx it's silly mistake of me it is workingthx again

Comment: @WeatherVane but it is working now  i forgot braces as "UnholyShee"p corrected me

Answer (score 1):

The while loop in sauvegarder needs braces, otherwise it will only execute the fprintf call and never the line after that – UnholySheep